# 'Error capturing image' with Phonegap on Android

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I need to capture an image with my Phonegap app. On iOS everything works fine but on Android (via Phonegap Build) it throws an error with "Error capturing image".

I added the following lines to my config.xml but that doesn't change anything:

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
```

My API call looks like that:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#cameraPreview', function() {
        pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;

        navigator.camera.getPicture(onGetPictureSuccess, onGetPictureFail, {
          quality: 40,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPG,
          targetWidth: 1000,
          targetHeight: 1000,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
          correctOrientation: 1
        });
    });
```

I use Phonegap 3.7 with Phonegap Build.

Comment: Please include the header line from `config.xml`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok, now I know the answer. The problem is the `saveToPhotoAlbum: true` option. Android doesn't recognize this. When I delete this option everything works fine.

Comment: Is this a known issue with Cordova? I am upgrading from Cordova 3.5.0 and in that version it worked correctly with saveToPhotoAlbum option set.

Comment: before I tell the client that it is fixed. let me tell you, I love you. it was working for long time suddenly stopped working. thanks

Comment: I love you too, @johnny. This option works on some Android devices, and does not work on others. This should be added to the documentation of the plugin. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Check your cordova-camera-plugin version.
If it's under 4.0.1, this will be fixed by updating latest version.
Otherwise, I have no idea.

This is a known issue and already be fixed.
You can see more detail below link.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13781

Answer (score 1):

Updating `cordova-camera-plugin` to version 4.0.2 or higher should fix the problem with saving to the photo album.

Since Android 8, saving a photo in the photo album requires the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, but this is not requested by versions of `cordova-camera-plugin` older than 4.0.2.

For more information:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13781
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/pull/308

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The permission requirements have changed in different versions of Android and different SDK versions. Make sure you are using the appropriate plugin version for your target OS version.

For anyone seeing this same issue with cordova-camera-plugin <=4.2.0 on Android 10, you can set `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />`

See this ticket for more info: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/issues/611